# ImageView on a GridView

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I have a `GridView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/DarkSlateGray"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="none" >
    </GridView></LinearLayout>
```

I want to add an ImageView on top of this.

Tried `<include>`:

```
<include layout="@layout/connection"/>
```

connection.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_connection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/globe_connected_icon_48"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></RelativeLayout>
```

But result looks like this:

[image: Grid2]

Is there a way to show it on top of the `GridView` like this:

[image: Grid3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Linear Layout to a Relative Layout, then have both the grid view and the image view align to the top left of the parent. Make sure the the image view is below the grid view so that it appears on top.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `LinearLayout` orientation to vertical and place the `ImageView` above the `GridView` code. For `LinearLayout` you can provide attributes to define where in the layout a view will be, such attributes: `gravity` and `layout_gravity`. `RelativeLayout` provides similar attributes: ex.`layout_alignParentTop`. Also, use `android:background="@null"` in your `ImageView` if you want the white boarder around your image to be transparent.

Comment: Tried that already, empty space covers top instead of left while pushing the GridView down.